# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) while scraping-twitter

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter

I'm trying to scrape tweets using this code but I get always
"JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" I didn't understand why I'm getting this error or how can I solve it

```
enter code here
from twitter_scraper import get_tweets
import pandas as pd

tweets = get_tweets("draught", pages=4)
tweets_df = pd.DataFrame()
for tweet in tweets:
  print('Keys:', list(tweet.keys()), '\n')
  break
# Running the code for one keyword and extracting the relevant data
for tweet in tweets:
  _ = pd.DataFrame({'Text' : [tweet['text']],
                    'Date' : tweet['date'],
                    'Time' : tweet['time'],
                    'Location' : tweet['place'],
                    
                    })
  tweets_df = tweets_df.append(_, ignore_index = True)
tweets_df.head()
```

the error I'm getting:

```
enter code here

JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-cfb1880e2fd7> in <module>()
      4 tweets = get_tweets("draught", pages = 10)
      5 tweets_df = pd.DataFrame()
----> 6 for tweet in tweets:
      7   _ = pd.DataFrame({'text' : [tweet['text']],
      8                     'Date' : tweet['date'],

5 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: can you please paste the full stack trace of your error. It looks like this error is occuring in code you are not showing.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: error may mean you have empty string instead of JSON

Comment: @ChrisDoyle i have pasted the full stack trace of the error now thank you for reminding me

Comment: @furas thank you for the advices i will consider them in my next steps, this is my first question on stackoverflow.